# Issues on animating a conditionally rendered component using React-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I am new with react-spring. I am having trouble animating a component whenever it unmounts. I have a simple card with an onClick handler that's responsible for conditionally displaying my Overlay component. The animation works fine when mounting (from & enter works), but when closing the overlay, the component just disappears without animation (leave does not work). I suspect it's because of the conditional rendering of the component but I've been struggling for hours trying to find a solution for this one. Any help would be appreciated!

**My current code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-leftpad-h3vmv

**What I'm trying to achieve:** https://codesandbox.io/s/048079xzw

P.S. The latter is using mauerwerk's lib. I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were missing is this:

```
return expand.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
  item && <animated.div
  // ...etc
```

When you're controlling the mounting of a single component with `useTransition`, you need to conditionally render it based on the `item` being passed. In your case, when it's `false` it won't render (which will unmount if already mounted) and when it's `true` it will render (mount if unmounted).

Here's a working sandbox forked from yours: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-agnesi-cty5g.

### A little more info

The first argument to `useTransition` is the list you want to transition. That watches for changes and sends back an array mapped with each item, a key and a style object (`props`) based on whether the item is truthy (entering) or falsy (leaving). So for a transition that mounts/unmounts a single element, conditionally rendering based on the truthiness of the item is key.

Check out [the examples again here](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition) and you'll see the differences between transitioning a list, a toggle between two elements, and a single item.

For a list, no need to check for the existence of the item because the array changes.

For toggling between two elements, you use the truthiness of `item` to determine which element to render.

For a single element, `item` determines whether to render at all. This means it won't mount initially when you default to `false`, and will make sure you don't render 2 items whenever your `isActive` value changes.